# window login user name in window authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Actually I want to show the the user which is login on window .but when I write this parameter  and run on intranet

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

then it shows

> NT AUTHORITY\IUSR

I want to show the username. When I run through VB software it shows window user name.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `User.Identity.Name`:

```
If User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    Label1.Text = User.Identity.Name
Else
    Label1.Text = "Anonymous user"
End If
```

Comment: It shows on the same pc on which I make the program  "Anonymous user"

Comment: This means that you haven't authenticated. What authentication are you using?

Comment: sir window authentication ..and actually we have to give access of website to the third party .so we enable anonymous access to true .but when we disable it shows user name but according to requirement we have to maintain anonymous access to enable ??

Comment: I don't understand what you are talking about: you want to give anonymous access to your site to some third party and then you expect some username to show? Where do you expect this username will come from in your opinion? ASP.NET won't invent it. The user must authenticate himself if you hope to be able to display an username. That's the whole point of authentication after all :-)

Comment: And where does this client enters his login name in your application? How are you authenticating him? What authentication scheme are you using? I think you should step away from the keyboard for a moment and give a second thought on what you are doing.

Comment: sir in asp.net is there any way to get the person name which is login on the client system and accessing website ??

Comment: Yes, using Integrated Windows Authentication (NTLM). For this to work the client and the server must be in the same Windows Domain. If they are not on the same domain you can use Forms Authentication, but in this case the client must explicitly authenticate on your site by providing a username and password.

Comment: very very thanx sir actually I am Oracle dba and new to asp.net .your advice surly help me . is there nay link which will help me about client name  ??

Comment: What do you want to read about? Windows or Forms authentication? For Windows Authentication here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx. For Forms authentication here's a link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx